# How to Auto-size cell in datagridview according to data size

Tags: c#, .net

I searched for Autosizing of cell but found Auto-size row and column how can I make particular cell autosize (in terms of height since column width will be fixed)according to data size  of that particular cell?
can it be done using some property of datagridview?

Comment: I dont think you can resize a particular cell you have to use AutoResizeRow and column to find a workaround for your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code make `Cell Auto-size Vertically` depending on the data loaded

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It can help you

dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

where 0 is column index

Comment: Using this i am able to resize it horizontally how can i do it vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it through properties of DataGridView, Set the following properties. Setting follwing properties will allow the cell to expand (Vertically or horizontally) to show the full content without any truncation. These cell size expansion will result in either row or column size change where the cell exisit.

1. `AutoSizeRowsMode` = AllCells
2. `AutoSizeColumnsMode` = DisplayedCells

Comment: Using this I am able to resize it horizontally how can I do it vertically?

Comment: @Durga If you want to resize it vertically then you have to set that column with fixed size. Then it will resize vertically.

Comment: My column is of fixed width

Comment: @Durga If you need only vertical expansion of cells then Set AutoSizeColumnMode to None and check.

Comment: `AutoSizeRowsMode = AllCells`
`AutoSizeColumnsMode = none` I have set properties like this ,but it doesn't auto expand vertically